# Remmina Copy-Paste issue

Tags: copy, xrdp, rdp, remmina, paste

I utilize the Remmina software in order to connect through the XRDP service in a remote Ubuntu server. However, I cannot use the copy-paste functions to copy information from the remote machine to my personal host and vice versa. Specifically, I use the 1.12 version of the Remmina.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately that's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1439478) in Remmina 1.12 running on Ubuntu 15.04-16.04 and you have a few options:

- Do nothing and live with it  **:-(** (That's always an option)
- Install [the Remmina PPA](https://launchpad.net/~remmina-ppa-team/+archive/ubuntu/remmina-next) on 16.04. **:-)**

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt dist-upgrade
  ```
- Upgrade Ubuntu to Bionic 18.04 [which has version 1.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/remmina) **:D** (a bit of overkill, but it's also an option)

  ```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```

Comment: Lacks pretty pictures and steps like add ppa, sudo apt install, etc. but +1 :) Also the Xenial bug fix has been triaged...

Comment: Mentally sending you a second +1 in virtual / metaphysical form. Shouldn't there be a `sudo apt install ...` after the `sudo apt update` you just added? ;)

Comment: I have installed the Reminna PPA on Ubuntu 16.04. However, what are the configurations to use the copy-paste capability with my personal host?

Comment: @Fabby: Xmm, the dist-upgrade was conducted successfully (now I have the new Remmina version), but I still cannot use the copy-paste between the remote and my personal host.

Comment: @Fabby: Specifically, concerning the client side (personal host), I executed the commands in the second bullet of your answer. On the other side (server-remote host), I think that it isn't necessary to install Remmina. Remmina has upgraded successfully. Also, I don't find restart option in the Remmina menu. Could you edit your answer and give me more specific instructions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ezazel Ping me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04, fresh installed, Remmina 1.2.0-rcgit-29, zero advanced configurations in my remote connection; but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @OliverSosa I'll raise you remmina 1.4.20 and it *still* doesn't work (although I could have sworn it worked previously)